# Python troubles while working with stream

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here][1]I am creating a text game so I do have one file with commands, if I run this file the game starts. The second file is a .txt and I am saving commands into that file so when I shut everything down, I can see which commands did I input in the game.

The problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to import the commands into the console when I input some command (for example command: ´load´).

My goal is that after I input ´load´ the game would input slowly all the commands which I have in my .txt and then I will be able to play the game from the point where I saved my commands.

btw. I ha saved the commands in this form: "command" "command" ... so there are spaces between them

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqX3s.png  Image

Comment: you can read you file: `content = open("saved_commands.txt", "r").read()`

Comment: How can I input commands which I will read?

Comment: You do not need to. Input stream is designed to read user input data, but in your case, once you have stored commands, just read them and call necessary methods...

Comment: soubor = open("save.txt","r").read()    soubor.close() This doesnt work

Comment: Could you please provide some code? What have you tried so far, what is your approach?

Comment: `open('file')` returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which can be closed again. `file_object.read()`, however, returns the _file contents_ as a string.  If you need further assistance, please provide a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AdamPeter please include your code as text, not an image.

Comment: use the `dict` datatype for command execution like this: `def foo(arg1,arg2):print(arg1,arg2); comms={"bar":foo}`

Answer (score 1):

I am going with a simple example here, my commands.txt has a few lines – each line is a command. The first item on each line corresponds to the operation and the remaining two are the arguments to that operation.

1. command to add the numbers
2. command to subtract second from first
3. command to multiply of two numbers

**script.py**

```
def execute_command(a,b,c):
    if a == 1:
        return b+c
    elif a == 2:
        return b-c
    elif a == 3:
        return b*c
    else:
        return 0

def main():
    with open("commands.txt") as fp:
        for each_line in fp:
            command_string = each_line.strip().split(" ") 
            print(execute_command(*[int(i) for i in command_string]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**commands.txt**

```
1 2 3
2 3 2
3 2 3
```

**Output**

```
5
1
6
```

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: @LittleByBlue yep, that seems much cleaner. +1